# R Studio Not Recognizing Quartz

Tags: r, rstudio, quartz

I'm running a MacBook Air under Ventura 14.3 and R Studio Version 2023.06.2+561 (2023.06.2+561).

I'm trying to a knit an rmd. All the code chunks work perfectly. When I try to knit an HTML or PDF file, I receive an error message: X11 library is missing. Install from [www.xquartz.com](http://www.xquartz.com). I do that. I can see X11 in applications and right next to R Studio on the apps bar. Still no knitting.

I try to change the working directory. I get: cannot change working directory.

I attempt to install it via install.packages. I get: package ‘x11’ is not available for this version of R.

I've shut down and restarted the laptop.

Please get me unstuck.